# jQuery .bind() does not update value in 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

in jQuery 1.8.1, when I used the code below function validateValue() is being fired with updated values. In 1.9.1 it uses the 1st Value from the DOM and not what is typed in. Any solution or this?

```
function getValueFromInput() {
  var inputElement = $('#value');
  var dropdownElement = $('#currency');

  inputElement.bind('change keydown keyup',function() {
    var inputValue = $('#value').attr('value');
    validateValue(inputValue);
  });


  dropdownElement.bind('change keydown keyup',function() {
    validateValue(inputValue);
  });

}
```

Comment: This might help: http://jsfiddle.net/tz0opmf4/light/

Comment: `.bind()` shouldn't be used anymore, please switch to `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var inputValue = $('#value').attr('value');
```

I have to use:

```
var inputValue = $('#value').val();
```

Comment: `$('#value').attr('value');` is a pretty unconventional way of doing it! x)

Answer (score 0):

Also do not cache the value, instead find it from DOM element to reflect the latest value of input.

```
dropdownElement.bind('change keydown keyup',function() {
//validateValue(inputValue);
validateValue($('#value').val());
});
```